# location to downloaded the Configuration file '...-4c982-firebase-adminsdk-afeif-66aa57d3dc.json' from cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-platform

Developed demo Mobile App with Xamarin Forms(4.8) using Visual studio 2019 (v16.7) for Android iOS and UWP.
Added NuGet package Google.Colud.Firestore(2.1)
Created a new firebase project, and downloaded the configuration file to include in Visual studio library project.

Completed Development with testing for UWP. It was a good experience. UWP project is working as expected.
As with previous experience I was expecting that Android project will work without an changes. But I think it requires
additional changes.
Now when I am trying to get the location from where I have downloaded the Configuration
file '...-4c982-firebase-adminsdk-afeif-66aa57d3dc.json'.

Comment: To assist you, can you restate your question. It is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

I could locate the page

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?authuser=0#set-up-project-and-service-account

which I was not getting for long time.

I was searching at wrong locations.